# C++ operations on values given by multiset::equal_range

Tags: c++, multiset, equal-range

I'm trying to write a program that is taking 1000 random numbers from 0 to 9 and then counting how many times each number appeared:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    multiset<int> M;//multiset that contains 1000 random numbers from 0 to 9
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        r.insert(rand() % 10);
        s.insert(rand() % 10);
    }

    vector <int> R(10);//vector that stores how many times each number appeared 
    //(so R[0] equals how many times 0 appeared and so on)

    pair<multiset<int>::iterator, multiset<int>::iterator> zero = M.equal_range(0);
    R[0] = zero.second - zero.first;
```

The problem is in the last line (in which I'm trying to count the number of times 0 appeared), it underlines minus and says that no operator matches these operands. But why? Aren't zero.first and zero.second ends of compartments? And how to fix it?

*Edit: I have to use a multiset, vector and equal_range, these are the things my teacher picked, not me.*

Comment: why not map instead of multiset?

Comment: @Incomputable because that's what my teacher picked for this task and I don't really have any word in it.

Comment: put std::distance instead of minus then. Put first first.

Comment: @Incomputable thank you very much, this is what I've been looking for.

Comment: Ania please consider accepting @drbombe's answer, which will indicate that it indeed solved the issue. Also - powodzenia na UW

Comment: @Ania, I would also advise on the code quality. When taking modulo it is not going to be uniform anymore. One could also make it much more prettier by using standard algorithms and iterators.

Comment: map can't accept duplicates

Comment: @drbombe, it would be `++occurences[value]`, not inserts. It also automatically zero initializes them, sparing some lines of code and CPU cycles.

Comment: @drbombe we don't really need any duplicates in any container if our only task is to count occurrences of numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `distance(zero.first, zero.second)`. The `-` operator cannot be applied to multiset iterators.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I tested it and it works, I will use it.

Comment: Superb! can you upvote my answer? I need some scores : )

Answer (score -1):

This would be far easier using a map:

```
std::map<int, int> counts;
...
count[num]++; // map::operator[] will insert the value if it's not already in the sequence.
```

Comment: "this would be easier using [...]" does not answer the questions provided

Comment: alternatives to a poor or suboptimal approach can complement an already complete answer. unfortunately this is not complete